# Combination of tuples for a given the max magnitude of each element and max sum of elements

Tags: python, loops, combinations, combinatorics

I have two numbers

= max magnitude of each coefficient

= max sum of magnitudes

What is the possible combination of the tuples?

I have tried the following code but I do not get the correct result.

```
while i<=2 and i+j<=3:
    em.append((i,j))
    i+=1
while i<=2 and i+j<=3:
    em.append((i,j))
    j+=1
```

Ideally, I would like to have the following results.

```
(0,0),(0,1),(1,0),(1,1),(1,2),(2,1)
```

So each element is lesser than(or equal) to 2 and the sum of elements in the tuple (2+1 in the last tuple case) is lesser than equal to 3.

For the code above I am getting [(0, 0), (1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2)]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are trying to do

```
def fun(m,n):
    i = 0    
    em = []
    while i <= m:        
        j = 0
        while i+j <=n and j <=m:
            em.append((i,j))
            j =j+1
        i = i+1
    return em


fun(2,3)

[(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 0), (2, 1)]
```

Comment: Sort of but the elements in the tuple must be lesser than or equal to 2. So (0,3) shouldn't be there.

Comment: Also your function doesn't work for a lot of the other cases.

Comment: I just edited the code for the element to be less than or equal to 2.